# SmbFile URL path with password having an @

Tags: ntlm, samba, smb, jcifs, unknown-host

I am using the JCIFS library and I have the samba file URL as

```
SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb://domain;username:P@ssword@abc.com/share/filename.txt")
file.connect
```

Notice the password has an `@`. Samba file connect is failing giving an `java.net.UnknownHostException`. Other than parsing the URL and passing auth seperately using `NtlmAuthentication`, is there any other way...

In the Format URL I tried putting square brackets and that did not help.

Comment: Never use credentials in the URL. That is for quick and dirty hacks. Use the NtlmPasswordAuthentication object.

Answer (score 3):

URL Encode the password as below

```
URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
```

this will encode your password to -P%40ssword
This called present encoding.Check this Wikipedia [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to learn more about present encoding.

But this is not a good practice.Create a NtlmPasswordAuthentication to set authentication details.

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, username, password);
String path ="abc.com/share/filename.txt";
SmbFile file = new SmbFile(path,auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did UrlEncode of the password and that solved the problem.